How to automatically increase font size to fill N sheets of paper?
How do I say via (pure) CSS: "This document should print on two sheets of paper,
and not have any wasted white space on the last page"?
I.e., "Please automatically increase the font-size for me, until it the
document fills two pages, and no more. So I don't have to inch it up by
hand to find what is just right."
Yes, I saw
Font scaling based on size of container
but it isn't quite the same. For instance, two pages mean two containers, etc. I suppose.
Tinkering with
@media print { body { font-size: 20px; } }

works fine, but is tedious.

Not possible with CSS.

You’d need to iterate towards a solution using JavaScript.

May be you can use @media print

I was using @media print { } but forgot to mention it. Fixed. Thanks.
